# C function of double type sometimes works when declared in certain headers

Tags: c, function, double

I have this weird problem where sometimes this function not always work, and only works if it's declared in the same headers where it is called... It's a really strange thing because the compiler *it seems* even ignores if the files containing the function are included or not...

```
double mapRange(double value, double r1, double r2, double n1, double n2)
{
    double res = n1+(value-r1)*((n2-n1)/(r2-r1));
    printf("dividingby: %f", res);putchar('\n');
    return res;
}
```

as you can see when it prints the value it is correct however when I print the returned value from another function like main I get garbage numbers...
Worst thing is I tested it on a file by itself and it worked flawlessly, I know this seems like an error from my part but I really can't find an explanation for this... Has someone encountered something like that? Is my compiler broken? Is there any limits in C that I'm not aware of? I know too that I don't have much more code to offer than this which kind of makes it difficult for a diagnosis but it's from a rather not-so-small project for uni...

EDIT 1:
OK so

// main.c

```
 #ifndef UTIL_H
    #define UTIL_H
    #include "util.h"
    #endif /*UTIL_H*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Matrix* volcan = readVolcano("test.txt");
    double t;
    mapRange(7.0, 1.0, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0,&t);
    printf("%f\n..\n", t);
    mat_printinfo(volcan);
    mat_printmat(volcan, NULL);
    weighted_volcano(volcan, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    mat_free(volcan);
    return 0;
}
```

// util.c

```
#include "util.h"


/*
    Retorna una transformacion de value que esta entre r1 y r2 a un valor que esta
    entre n1 y n2, con tal que tenga la misma relacion con el rango [n1, n2] como
    value tenga con el rango [r1, r2]
*/


double mapRange(double value, double r1, double r2, double n1, double n2, double* result)
{
    double res = n1+(value-r1)*((n2-n1)/(r2-r1));
    printf("dividingby: %f", res);putchar('\n');
    if(result!=NULL)
    *result = res;
    return res;
}
```

I'm absolutely sure there's not a duplicate in definition, I've also rebuilt the project many times...

```
D:\Code\C\volcan\cc1.exe    [Warning] command line option '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
D:\Code\C\volcan\main.c In function 'main':
52  19  D:\Code\C\volcan\main.c [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
D:\Code\C\volcan\main.c In function 'open_volcano':
91  7   D:\Code\C\volcan\main.c [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
D:\Code\C\volcan\main.c In function 'test_volcano':
119 13  D:\Code\C\volcan\main.c [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
D:\Code\C\volcan\cc1.exe    [Warning] command line option '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
D:\Code\C\volcan\volcantobmp.c  In function 'weighted_volcano':
38  6   D:\Code\C\volcan\volcantobmp.c  [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
40  6   D:\Code\C\volcan\volcantobmp.c  [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
D:\Code\C\volcan\cc1.exe    [Warning] command line option '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
```

the output of the IDE

EDIT 2:
So it seems the problem was here

// util.h

```
#include "headers.h"
```

it was empty...

Comment: Do you have another function named `mapRange` that takes different parameters? Do you have a prototype for this function that is visible everywhere it is called? Do you have the warnings turned up on your compiler, and do you see any when you compile?

Comment: when  you import this function from another file, post your code. show your usage and how you are importing/declaring

Comment: Sounds like this function `mapRange` is defined in one C source file, and the calling function (like `main`) is defined in another.  So the question is, when `main` is being compiled, how does the compiler know that `mapRange` returns a `dounle`?  The answer is, the compiler needs to be able to see an *external prototype declaration* for `mapRange`.  Typically you put this in a header file, maybe `maprange.h`.  Then you use `#include` to pull `maprange.h` in to both source files as they are being compiled.

Comment: But if this isn't making sense, you'll want to find a tutorial on separate compilation, which can be confusing at first.

Comment: You missed the most important file. `util.h`, and those warnings don't match the code you've posted. You might want to make a [mcve] to highlight just the issue you're asking about. Given the warnings you posted I'm not surprised you have issues, but none of them seem to relate to this particular one.

Comment: Sooo... uuhhh... @SteveSummit 's answer made it work... can I ask why? Other functions in the project do not require them?? also thanks everyone for the feedback, I know this would be outside the scope of the og question but should I always declare prototypes on the headers?

Comment: In my opinion you ALWAYS need prototypes, and you should enable the warnings that complain loudly when you do not have them. Warnings in general are something your code should never have.

Comment: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title. The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept an answer. (You can post and accept your own answer.)

Comment: @KeithThompson i can't though right now, it says in two days... can I accept one of the comments as a answer?

Comment: @Kurinoku: No, you can't accept a comment as an answer. (If you like you can post a comment encouraging a commenter to post an answer.)

Comment: @Kurinoku It likely worked for the other functions because those functions returned `int`.  There's an old rule that functions were assumed to return `int` unless declared otherwise.  But that rule is obsolete, and (as other comments mentioned) a modern compiler will warn you if you call any function that hasn't been declared.  I wonder why yours didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SteveSummit gave me the solution it needed a prototype declaration for the function in util.h

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it is most likely that there is another "mapRange" function somewhere in your "code base".

Just to isolate the problem, I recommend renaming your "mapRange" function to something unique like appending today's date (mapRange_20181127) leaving mapRange call in main(). If your "code base" contains another function with name "mapRange", you will not face any error as linker would find the "other" mapRange.

If this is the case, choosing another meaningful name would solve your issue.

Hope this helps!

**Update:**
I guess while I'm typing, you posted more details and you got your answer :).

Comment: yes thank you either way for taking your time and trying to help, i really apreciate it